# Extracting raster attribute table from raster using gdalinfo

Tags: python, gdal

```
_rat = subprocess.check_output('gdalinfo -json ' + dataset_uri, shell=True)
```

I want to extract the raster attribute table of a .tif file. In the command above, I am able to get the info into `_rat` but not sure how to extract the `rat` section from _rat. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `_rat` is a string that is valid JSON. You can convert that JSON into a python `dict` that will allow you to access the elements with ease. `gdalinfo` doesn't provide the full raster attribute table as I recall, but there is still band-level statistics that are meaningful.

```
import json
import subprocess

dataset_uri = 'input.tif'
_rat = subprocess.check_output('gdalinfo -json ' + dataset_uri, shell=True)
data = json.loads(_rat) # load json string into dictionary
print data

# to get band-level data
bands = data['bands']
```

Comment: thanks @Logan! This works. You can get the raster attribute table like this: `data['rat']`. Latest version of gdalinfo has this capability

Comment: Note that woth GDAL 2.1 you can use`gdal.Info` see http://gdal.org/python/ for the syntax, look at `gdal.,InfoOptions` as well, avoid a subprocess call.